# In Java XOR with three true inputs returns true. Why?

Tags: java, logic, xor

The following code

```
System.out.println("1 0 0: " + (true ^ false ^ false));
System.out.println("1 0 1: " + (true ^ false ^ true));
System.out.println("1 1 0: " + (true ^ true ^ false));
System.out.println("1 1 1: " + (true ^ true ^ true));
System.out.println("0 0 0: " + (false ^ false ^ false));
System.out.println("0 0 1: " + (false ^ false ^ true));
System.out.println("0 1 0: " + (false ^ true ^ false));
System.out.println("0 1 1: " + (false ^ true ^ true));
```

outputs:

```
1 0 0: true
1 0 1: false
1 1 0: false
1 1 1: true
0 0 0: false
0 0 1: true
0 1 0: true
0 1 1: false
```

Why does XOR returns `true` when all three inputs are `true`?

If it's valid logic how can I implement logic that returns `true` **only** if one of the input elements is `true` (no matter how many inputs I provide)?

Comment: `true ^ true ^ true` can be written (for understanding) as  `( true ^ true ) ^ true` which is  `true`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
If you want a true result, if one and only one inputs is true you can use:

(a ^ b ^ c ) ^ ( a && b && c )

the test case result:

true true true = false
true true false = false
true false true = false
true false false = true
false true true = false
false true false = true
false false true = true
false false false = false
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the right-hand side only needs to test _any two_ variables. I also modified it to use `&& !` to join the two sides, because a) I find the intent clearer this way, and b) if the left side is false, there's no need to evaluate the right side:

`(a ^ b ^ c) && !(a && b)`

(I did a quick nine-way test on this, and it worked.)

Comment: (And by "nine-way test", I mean "eight-way test" :-) )

Answer (score 11):

Because true xor true = false, and false xor true is true.  xor is associative, so group the values any way you please!

To decide that only one of them is true, you could add the values together as integers and see if the answer is 1.

I'm answering this as a general programming question, it really isn't particular to Java.

Comment: I just realised `org.apache.commons.lang.BooleanUtils#xor(boolean[])` does exactly what I need. Thank for an idea anyway!

Comment: @parxier org.apache.commons.lang.BooleanUtils.xor(new Boolean[] { Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.TRUE}) returns also true, which is not what you want in your question

Answer (score 11):

Here's a Java 8 way of determining if exactly one boolean is true:

```
Stream.of(b1, b2, b3, ...)
        .filter(b -> b)
        .count() == 1;
```

Comment: That's easily expandable, I like it!

Answer (score 7):

Think about how the compiler evaluates this:

```
(true ^ true) ^ true
```

After first term `true ^ true`, which is `false`, has been evaluated:

```
(false) ^ true ==> true
```

Answer (score 3):

`true ^ true ^ true` can be written (for understanding) as  `( true ^ true ) ^ true` which is  `true`.

If A, B, C are inputs, for the logic that you are looking for, you need something like this

```
(A & !B & !C) | (!A & B & !C) | (!A & !B & C)
```

Comment: Ok. Is it the shortest expression.. really? :-)

Comment: This is what I was able to think of. I'm not sure how to simplify that.

Comment: A?b?false:!c:b?!c:c maybe? Or a?!(b||c):b^c

Answer (score 2):

'^' is a binary logical operator, not an n-ary operator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is it discovered and highlighted, but I noticed a thing that if we add all values together (no matter how many are there) and see what's left after division by 2 we can notice the result is `false` if `0` left and `true` if `1` left.

Example:

`1 ^ 0 ^ 1 ^ 1 = 1` 
and 
`(1+0+1+1)%2 = 1`

They are the same.
Please, correct or guide me who has a clue about this case.